# How to extract this node content using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm scraping [this website](https://insolvencyinsider.ca/filing/). I'm specifically interested in extracting the content found in the last script node [script node snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b4dX.png). Thus far I have tried the following:

```
url <- "https://insolvencyinsider.ca/filing/"
ii <- read__html(url)
fwp <- ii %>%
  htl_nodes("body") %>%
  xml_find_first(xpath = "/script[15]") %>%
  html_text() # Not text so I wouldn't expect this to work.

#> character (empty)


fwp <- ii %>%
  htl_nodes("body") %>%
  xml_find_first(xpath = "/script[15]") %>%
  html_attr("window.FWP_JSON") # Don't think this makes sense since its not an attribute?

 #> chr NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can regex it out with the following pattern then parse with jsonlite

```
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)
library(stringr)

text <- read_html('https://insolvencyinsider.ca/filing/') %>% 
  toString()

data <- stringr::str_match(text, 'window\\.FWP_JSON = (.*?);\\n')[,2]

result <- jsonlite::parse_json(data)
```

---

Regex:

[image]